# Is there a desktop RSS app?

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro. Now, I am looking for a desktop RSS reader app that integrates with Feedly. (BTW I’m not a fan of web-based apps.) Is there an app like that? If so, how do you install it?

Comment: https://quiterss.org/ ?

Comment: it won't integrate with feedly. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Feedreader* seems to support Feedly, consider checking for details on it's  [GitHub page](https://jangernert.github.io/FeedReader/).

**Keep in mind:**

It is most likely not available in the default Ubuntu sources but the project github page mentiones a PPA.

Comment: How do i install it? After running the command in their ubuntu installation page, i get an error:

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eviltwin1/feedreader-stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: The ppa seems to have builds for Xenial and Trusty - check: https://launchpad.net/~eviltwin1/+archive/ubuntu/feedreader-stable/+packages

Comment: And because im using yakkety yak, i can't install it. :-7

Comment: I somehow managed to install feedreader and it's brilliant.

Comment: @RichardMcGonagol Glad to hear